# PutParcelable cannot be applied to Place.Type error?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to pass map data from the map fragment on an activity to a separate fragment on the same activity.

When the user clicks on a maps POI, I make a call to google and grab a bunch of data including Place.Type which I want to pass on to the new fragment, unfortunately Place.Type is returning an error saying is wrong type.. unparcelable.
Android studio offered me an option of casting to parcelable which I tried and crashed with.

Looking in the reference, google says that Place.Types implements parcelable so am a little confused about why this is failing

I am sure there is a way to loop thought and recast or something but my lack of knowledge holds me back can someone please help here?

```
public class ZombieMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener, GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private final int PERM_REQUEST_LOCATION_INT = 1;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient FusedLocationClient;
    private String apiKey;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zombie_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //location
        FusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        //places API stuff
        apiKey  = getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);

    }




    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    //perm check
        ...{
         mapSetup();
        }
    }

    private void requestPerms() { ... }

//catch request reply
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode,
            String permissions[],
            int[] grantResults)    { ... }
    }

    private void mapSetup() {...}

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {...}

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
        makeToast("This is you");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPoiClick(final PointOfInterest poi) {
        //distance check and throw out if to far

        //great place to think about a caching system for types.. to cut down on requests

        //placeId to place type method
        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
        String placeId = poi.placeId;
        List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.TYPES);
        FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, placeFields);

        placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FetchPlaceResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FetchPlaceResponse fetchPlaceResponse) {
                Place place = fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace();
                List<Place.Type> types = place.getTypes();
                String placeName = poi.name;
                makeLootFragment(types,placeName);

                makeToast(placeName);
            }
        });
    }

    private void makeLootFragment(List<Place.Type> _types,String name){

        //pack it for sending
        Bundle lootBundle = new Bundle();

        lootBundle.putParcelable("bLootTypes" , (Parcelable) _types);//not working
        lootBundle.putString("bName",name);

        FragmentManager lootFragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction LootTrans = lootFragMan.beginTransaction();
        LootFragment lootFragment = new LootFragment();
        lootFragment.setArguments(lootBundle);
        LootTrans.add(R.id.lootContainer,lootFragment);
        LootTrans.addToBackStack("LootStack");
        LootTrans.commit();

    }





    private void makeToast(String words) {
        Toast.makeText(this, words, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Any other advice based on the terrible coding displayed here would also be very appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I made a "shadow class" to hold all the data from the place request

```
public class PlaceDataHolder implements Parcelable {

    private Place placeData;


    public PlaceDataHolder(Place _place){
        placeData = _place;
    }
}
```

When I had finished writing this class that takes in the object from the google OnSuccessListener and slams it into a holder variable just so I can implement the Parcelable on said class...

Android studio then had a bunch of complaints which it had auto fixes for resulting in all this wonderful extra code

```
    protected PlaceDataHolder(Parcel in) {
    placeData = in.readParcelable(Place.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Creator<PlaceDataHolder> CREATOR = new Creator<PlaceDataHolder>() {
    @Override
    public PlaceDataHolder createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new PlaceDataHolder(in);
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceDataHolder[] newArray(int size) {
        return new PlaceDataHolder[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeParcelable(placeData, flags);
}

public List<Place.Type> getTypes(){
    return placeData.getTypes();
}
```

This last bit was generated with next to zero thought by me, just hovered the redlines and alt+entered my way to to this glorious working solution

Answer (score 0):

The Class of the Object you want to send should implement Parcelable interface as follow -

```
public class Student implements Parcelable {

    private Integer rollno;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;


    protected Student(Parcel in) {

        age = in.readInt();
        name  = in.readString();
        rollno = in.readInt();

    }

    public Student(Integer age, String name, Integer rollno) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }


    public static final Creator<Student> CREATOR = new Creator<Student>() {
        @Override
        public Student createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Student(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Student[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Student[size];
        }
    };


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public Integer getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }

    public void setRollno(Integer rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }



    public static Creator<Student> getCREATOR() {
        return CREATOR;
    }


  @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {

        parcel.writeInt(age);
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeInt(rollno);


    }
}
```

So what you should do is make a class and implement Parcelable and write the Place.Type content into its members and then pass it to other Fragment

Comment: so the implementing parcelable thing is quite hard for me to do.. you very nicely copied out the constructor for a class that I can write but the class I am working from is from google..

The real Question is why does Place.Tytpe, that according to the documents already implements parcelable, need to be plastered onto another class to get used? as IO am still confused as to why a parcelable class is not parcelable :D

Also do I have that right just make a new class that implements and transfer the data in a 1 for 1 manner across?

Comment: bundle.putParcelableArrayList() have you tried this method